# Babel es2015 Arrow Function error

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

I'm using es2015 Arrow functions in a React component that is throwing an error when I declare `myfunction() {...}`. The error doesn't exist if write it like so `myFunction : function () {...}`. I do not have any issues compiling with Browserify/Babelify - this only happens with the below example.

```
import React from 'react';

module.exports =  React.createClass({
  // render : function () { // <--- this works
  render() { // <---- this throws an error
    return (
      <div>Kaboom.</div>
      );
  }
});
```

---

```
/* RenderService.js */
require("babel-register")({
  plugins: ["transform-react-jsx","transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
});

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

module.exports = {
  renderReport : function (reportId) {
    var TestComp =  require('./TestCompoennt');

    var ReactComponent = React.createFactory(TestComp,'div');

    return ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(ReactComponent());
  }
};
```

---

> Error: renderApproval() {
>                   ^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Where are you using an arrow function? Also, you show `render()` in your first code sample and `renderApproval` in your error message.

Comment: @torazaburo Why not use arrow functions? I used render() as the example code.. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use a preset-es2015, this plugin includes `transform-es2015-shorthand-properties`, that one you need to transform this:

```
var z = function() { return 'z'; };
var x = {
  z
}
```

to this:

```
var z = function() { return 'z'; };
var x = {
  z: z
}
```

Or in your case

```
var x = {
  z() {
    return 'z';
  }
}
```

And also includes:

- check-es2015-constants
- transform-es2015-arrow-functions
- transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions
- transform-es2015-block-scoping
- transform-es2015-classes
- transform-es2015-computed-properties
- transform-es2015-destructuring
- transform-es2015-for-of
- transform-es2015-function-name
- transform-es2015-literals
- transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
- transform-es2015-object-super
- transform-es2015-parameters
- transform-es2015-shorthand-properties
- transform-es2015-spread
- transform-es2015-sticky-regex
- transform-es2015-template-literals
- transform-es2015-typeof-symbol
- transform-es2015-unicode-regex
- transform-regenerator

Link http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/